# When I click the delete button the top item on the list deletes. How can I fix it?

Tags: reactjs

So I am trying to delete user name and image when in this panel I created. When I click the delete button on any item the first item on the list automatically deletes. WHat can I do to ensure the right item on the list gets deleted?

```
 showfriendsrequest = () => {
            const { show } = this.state;
            let URL = 'https://swapi.co/api/people/';
            let HEADERS = {'content-type':'application/json', 'authorization':'sdjfjdskfj45j4ekj'};

            axios.get(URL, HEADERS)
            .then((response) => {
                let usersData = response.data.results;
                console.log(usersData);
                let users = [{name:"",img:""}];
                let names = [];
                let imgs = [];

                for (let i=0; i<usersData.length; i++) {
                    let id = i;
                    let currentName = usersData[i]['name'];
                    let currentImages = usersData[i]["image"]
                    users.push({"id":id, 'name':currentName, "img":currentImages});
                }
               this.setState({users, show:!show});
            });
    }
                deletefriendrequest = (index,e) => {
                    const users = Object.assign([], this.state.users);
                    users.splice(index, 1);
                    this.setState({users:users})
                    alert(`${this.state.users.name}`)
                }
        addfriend = () => {
            alert(`You just added a new friend ${this.state.name}`);
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't use mutation, instead you can filter the array and replace your delete function with something like

```
deletefriendrequest = (index, e) => {
   this.setState({
     users: this.state.users.filter((user, i)=> i !== index ) 
 }
```

Or better even, you could target the user by id instead of index, and on the onClick simply pass the user.id